# Why Searchview search icon is not showing with collapseActionView property?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I am creating searchview in android toolbar but whenever, I mention collapseActionView property inside menu.xml item  like:-

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/search_view_layout"/>
```

Here search_view_layout.xml is as bellow:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="35dp"/>
```

in this case my searchView is looking as bellow image:-

[image]

In above image search icon doesn't appear. when I click this search title SearchView Open as:-

[image]

I don't understand,Why not hide the Kart menu item, and not import any style properties from style.xml:-

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/search</item>
    <item name="goIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">35dp</item>
```

But I want to design Searchview as bellow:-

[image: Desired Searview for App]

Any suggestion would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

In your menu add

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    />
```

In your java class

```
   SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(((AppCompatActivity) context).getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); 
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

To apply style , add this in your style.xml

```
  <style name="MyToolbar" parent="AppTheme">
   <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/searchStyle</item>
  </style>

 <style name="searchStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar">
    <item name="queryHint">@string/search</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

And finally apply the above theme in your toolbar

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/MyToolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its shows normal searchview. I have already achieve this. I want to create seachview like attached image.Please go through my searchview style.